# Logic Pro X: create summing track stack of already existing track stacks

Tags: mixing, daw, logic-pro

I would like to create a track stack of track stacks. When I attempt to create, it says that I can only create a "folder" track stack and not a "summing" track stack.

My questions:

- How comes? Why is this a thing, does anybody know the reason behind this?
- How do I work around this issue?

Comment: I don't know Logic, but I guess there must be an option for a "bus track" or "fx track" to achieve that.

Comment: I think it’s not possible to make summing into summing,you can use VCA faders or try you question on Logic Pro Help forum

Comment: Hey, thank you for the comments you all, I appreciate that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How comes? Why is this a thing, does anybody know the reason behind this?

No idea.

> How do I work around this issue?

Just use buses and auxiliary channels.